# What version of Entity Framework Core is installed?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need to find out what version of Entity Framework Core is installed on my machine so I can reference the correct documentation on how to set up models correctly with the version installed on my machine.

What is the command to check the version I have on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Command Needed**

```
dotnet ef --version
```

I was able to enter this command in Powershell and it showed me the version installed.

[image]